# Can't import springframework.security.extensions and find saml() method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer does not exist

At least i can't import **org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer** in my Security Configuration class the method **saml()** has not been defined.

the source code of of **SecurityConfiguration.java**:

```
    package com.hem.configuration;

    import com.hem.properties.ServerProxy;
    import com.hem.properties.ServerSsl;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
 import org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer;

    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String HTTPS = "https";

        @Value("${security.saml2.metadata-url}")
        private String metadataUrl;

        @Value("${saml.entity.id}")
        private String entityId;

        @Autowired
        private ServerProxy serverProxy;

        @Autowired
        private ServerSsl serverSsl;

        @Autowired
        private SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl samlUserDetailsServiceImpl;

        @Override
        protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/saml*").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/images/apple-touch-icon.png").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .apply(saml()) //<-can't find this method
                    .userDetailsService(samlUserDetailsServiceImpl)
                    .serviceProvider()
                        .keyStore()
                            .storeFilePath(serverSsl.getKeyStore())
                            .password(serverSsl.getKeyStorePassword())
                            .keyname(serverSsl.getKeyAlias())
                            .keyPassword(serverSsl.getKeyStorePassword())
                            .and()
                        .protocol(HTTPS)
                        .hostname(String.format("%s:%s", serverProxy.getHost(), serverProxy.getPort()))
                        .basePath("/")
                        .entityId(entityId)
                        .and()
                    .identityProvider()
                    .metadataFilePath(this.metadataUrl);
        }
    }
```

---

Dependencies in my **pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
</dependency>
```

Please share your experience, if you know how to resolve this issue.

If you need more info - i'll fix the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the below Maven dependency in `pom.xml` file

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-saml-dsl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And add the below static import in above class

```
import static org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer.saml;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add:

```
import static org.springframework.security.extensions.saml2.config.SAMLConfigurer.saml;
```